# Pipelining between PowerShell and C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, powershell, named-pipes

I'm having a hard time piping data from a PowerShell script into a C# program.

[Thanks to this answer I was given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056955/pipelining-between-two-separate-powershell-processes), I've come up with a working solution for piping data between **two PowerShell scripts**(`Sender.ps1` and `Receiver.ps1`).

**The problem is**, this script doesn't work when translated into C# code.
Even if I invoke `Receiver.ps1` in C# via the `PowerShell` class, it still doesn't work.

[This answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19456521/5236337) leads me to believe that the namespace for the pipes isn't the same, but when I tried adding `Global` to the beginning of each pipe it didn't do anything.  Again, it works in the two `.ps1`'s if I run as PowerShell scripts, but if I invoke one of the scripts from C#, or translate it directly into C#, it stops working altogether.

**Does anyone know anything about namespaces and pipelining in Windows?**

---

**Sender.ps1**: doesn't interact with C# program, other than sending data through the pipe

```
## Establish Pipe
  $pipe = New-Object System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream("Global\\.pipe\brokenPipe");
  $pipe.Connect();
  $stream = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($pipe);

## Communicate through Pipe
  SendStuff();

## Close Pipe
  $stream.Dispose();
  $pipe.Dispose();
```

---

**Receiver.ps1:** PowerShell program for reading from the pipe.  **Works** if I right-click and run as PowerShell.  **Doesn't work** if I invoke it via C#'s PowerShell, it just hangs at `WaitForConnection()`.  The C# program is invoking the script correctly, I tested this with a dummy file full of information (which was read by C# correctly).  For some reason, the pipe stops working when it's run via my C# Application

```
## Establish Pipe
  $pipe = new-object System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream("Global\\.pipe\brokenPipe");
  $pipe.WaitForConnection();
  $stream = new-object System.IO.StreamReader($pipe);

## Communicate through Pipe
  ReadStuff();

## Close Pipe
  $stream.Dispose();
  $pipe.Dispose();
```

---

**C# Receiver Function:**  I made this as a substitute to `PowerShell.Create()`, and this doesn't work either (even though it's the exact same code as `Receiver.ps1`.

```
void PipeListener(){
## Establish Pipe
  var pipe = new System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream("Global\\.pipe\brokenPipe");
  pipe.WaitForConnection();
  var stream = new System.IO.StreamReader(pipe);

## Communicate through Pipe
  ReadStuff();

## Close Pipe
  stream.Dispose();
  pipe.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: The global namespace prefix is `Global\ `, not `Global\\ `.  You do not need to escape the backslash in Powershell.  Again, Powershell: `Global\pipename`, C#: `@"Global\pipename"` or `"Global\\pipename"`.

Comment: Thank you @Mitch , this is indeed the problem.  If you post this as an official answer, I'll accept it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The global namespace prefix is `Global\`, not `Global\\`. You do not need to escape the backslash in Powershell.

- Powershell: `Global\pipename`
- C#: `@"Global\pipename"` or `"Global\\pipename"`

Comment: Thanks.  I was escaping the backslash in PowerShell...talk about a rookie mistake!